# Auto delete hook in GNU Make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

By default `make` authomatically deletes targets when they are not needed anymore.

For example:

```
do_it: write_bar write_baz
    echo done > $@

.INTERMEDIATE: write_foo write_bar write_baz

write_foo:
    echo foo > $@

write_bar: write_foo
    cat $< > $@
    echo bar >> $@

write_baz: write_foo
    echo buz > $@
```

Here `write_foo` will be deleted after execution of both `write_bar` and `write_baz`.

I want not to simply remove file, but to do some actions just before `write_foo` deleted.

Can I change command for auto deletion or assign any hook for this action?

*Update:* autodeletion is applicable only for intermediate rules.

Comment: No, you cannot do that today.  In fact make doesn't even run the `rm` command, it just prints `rm` but internally it uses the `unlink()` system call to delete the files.

Answer (score 0):

- make (at least GNU Make) does not automatically delete successfully built targets (it does delete target if make was `kill`ed).
- `.DEFAULT` does not do what you expect it to do. See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html
- Invoking `make` on command line executes first target. Since your first target is write_foo, only write_foo will be executed.

If you invoke `make do_it`, all targets will be executed (and 3 files will appear in current directory).

Added after question update:

According to https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html, including intermediate target in prerequisites for `.PRECIOUS` special target prevents deleting it.

Comment: No, I want them be deleted after execution, so `PRECIOUS` doesn't help me. I just need to execute several commands with this file before deleting it.

Comment: @werehuman Did you consider keeping them with `.PRECIOUS` and delete them manually after doing what you want ?